# Populate Custom Table instead of Contacts table in CRM using Dynamics CRM Connector

Tags: xconnect, dynamics-crm-module

I need to sync the Sitecore contacts to CRM using Dynamics CRM Connector 2.0.1. As the synced contacts require further refinement, the synced contact needs to be added in a temp table in CRM instead of Contact table.

Can we change this configuration in the connector ?

Thanks
Samridhi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can simply do that. If you use a default  Dynamics CRM Connector pipeline to sync contacts to CRM, you only need to navigate `Pipelines -> xConnect Contacts to Dynamics Sync Pipelines`(1) folder, expand `Process Single Contact from xConnect Pipeline` (2) item and choose the `Resolve Dynamics Contact by Identifier` (3). Then you can find the `Entity Name` field there (4), which defines an entity where your contact will be saved in CRM (5). In your case, it will be some temp entity.

[image: Dynamics CRM Connector Change target entity]

Comment: Awesome, I changed the same setting. Thanks for confirmation @Artsem Prashkovich :)

Comment: Hi @artsem, I can see the connection being set with Custom Table and the contact is submitted on sync but the contact is not visible in CRM, does this require any other setting as well ?

Comment: Does your Custom Table have the same set of fields?

Comment: few fields are different, I have changed the mappings accordingly.

Comment: The custom Table is the entity name of CRM right? Does this accept spaces ? Do we take the entity display name or schema name here ?

Comment: yes, it is entity name. I don't know if it is accept spaces as I am not a Dynamics CRM developer, but any way, it is just a key of entity. If you can create an entity with spaces in a name - it is allowed.

Comment: @samridhisachdeva please, navigate to your pipeline batch and tick the following chackboxes: https://www.screencast.com/t/JTvbikyaETu5
Then re-run import again.

Comment: All these are ticked, there are no errors in logs , rather it says contact was submitted.

Comment: @samridhisachdeva could you share your log file?

Comment: How do i upload logs here ?

Comment: @samridhisachdeva As far as I see you have at least two persistent errors there:
`ManagedPoolThread #11 15:00:56 DEBUG [Data Exchange] Delta Settings is null. (pipeline: Read Contacts from xConnect Pipeline, pipeline step: Custom Filter Pipeline Step, pipeline step identifier: 282f61d3-b158-470a-af95-c3774e8d5e60)`
and
`Mapping from Contact Model to Dynamics Contact, pipeline step identifier: c45630ec-f29a-4bb7-af34-96d4b4de5498, mappings that failed: 1, value mapping ids: 0ba879f1-ab50-4b2f-bcac-b0cc84a02d68)`

Comment: @samridhisachdeva 
And also do you really need to export contact interactions to CRM? or do you need the contact itself only?

Comment: It's working now, I was using the entity name earlier, the contacts started moving after I entered the schema name for my entity.